# Simple form not passing parameter to controller RAILS

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a simple form with some javascript that shows some input fields or others depending on what the user selects. The weird behavior that I'm getting is that whichever `div` I put on top (for instance `div id="id1"`), the last f.input (`:motivo`) is not passed to the controller. If I change positions for the divs, then now the other `f.input :motivo` is not passed.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@vacacion, validate: true, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= display_base_errors @vacacion %>

  <%= f.input :tipo, label: 'Tipo', as: :select, collection: [["Registrar días de vacaciones utilizados", "tomadas"], ["Abonar días de vacaciones", "abonadas"]], required: true %>

  <div id="id1" style="display:none">
    <%= f.input :desde, label: 'Fecha inicio vacaciones', as: :datepicker, input_html: { value: @vacacion.desde.present? ? l(@vacacion.desde, format: :slash) : nil } %>
    <%= f.input :hasta, label: 'Fecha fin vacaciones', as: :datepicker, input_html: { value: @vacacion.hasta.present? ? l(@vacacion.hasta, format: :slash) : nil } %>
    <%= f.input :dias_tomados, label: 'Días de vacaciones utilizados', input_html: { min: 0 }, hint: '<div id="dias_habiles_div"></div>'.html_safe %>
    <%= f.input :motivo, input_html: { id: 'motivo_tomadas'} ,label: 'Motivo de los días tomados' %>
  </div>

  <div id="id2" style="display:none">
    <%= f.input :dias_abonados, label: 'Días de vacaciones a abonar', input_html: { min: 0 } %>
    <%= f.input :motivo, input_html: { id: 'motivo_abonadas'},label: 'Motivo de los días abonados' %>
  </div>

...

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#vacacion_tipo").change(function(){
      if(this.value == "tomadas"){
        $("#campos_vacaciones_abonadas").hide("slow");
        $("#campos_vacaciones_tomadas").show("slow");
      }

      if(this.value == "abonadas"){
        $("#campos_vacaciones_abonadas").show("slow");
        $("#campos_vacaciones_tomadas").show("slow");
      }
    });
```

I tried adding ids for the inputs in each case but that didn't help.
When I look at the console to check the parameters, every other param is passed ok but with 'motivo' I get `"motivo"=>""`

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple browsers? A change in HTML 4 made display:none still submit forms but not every browser worked at that time. Also can you edit your question to add the HTML generated for each of the states?

Comment: I don't know simple-form but from reading your code, how does simple-fom know when the form ends? If you look in your browser dev tools element inspector -- where do you find the `</form>` and is the last input elements included? This boils down to: is the generated HTML form like expected?

Comment: @Beartech Yes, tested in chrome and Safari. Same results. The HTML generated is exactly the same except for the first div, it also shows a data-parsley-id, and the other doesn't

Comment: You have a syntax error at `f.input :motivo, input_ html:`. You should also beware that attaching event handlers directly to the elements is a very flawed approach when Turbo (or any other AJAX framwork) is involved. It just leads to the classic "But WAAAH! my code works when I reload the page!". You should instead use [delegated event handlers](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) which is [what Stimulus does for you](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/).

Comment: You have 2 inputs with the same name. In this case the last one wins (overwrites the first). You will need to use different names for each element or manipulate the value before submission

Comment: @engineersmnky the last one overwrites the first even when is not being called by the function? All I need is to show a different label depending the case. How could I do that?

Comment: @RodrigoLadróndeGuevara correct. It is still a present input on the form regardless of it's visibility. You could add a different name in the input_html like you did with `id` e.g. `name: 'vacation[motivo_abonadas]'` or you could add a virtual attribute in the model.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a Rails or SimpleForm issue. It's just how forms work.

Look at the HTML that's produced, you'll see that you have two inputs with the name "motivo". The name attribute is what drives the parameters that come through from a form submission. And since you can't have two parameters with the same name, it's just submitting the last one it encounters, effectively overriding the first one.